# SQL select question with group by and order

Tags: select, sqlite

So I struggle with this rather simple task in SQLite. I have this table with columns

> hostname,kb,state

so each row is a KB installed/not installed on a server (according to WSUS).

Each server has few hundred rows there depending on it's age and OS version.
I want to simply see the latest (highest kb number) for each server in "installed" state.

This query does not seem to work unfortunately and shows some random kb and definitely not the highest:

```
Select 
   hostname,
   kb 
FROM
   patchstate 
WHERE 
   state='installed' 
GROUP BY hostname 
ORDER BY kb DESC
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `MAX(kb)`?

Comment: be aware, sometimes KB articles are released out of order.  Depending on what you're using this for, you may want to rethink this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the [SQLLite Max function](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) and Alias will allow you to rewrite your query as

```
SELECT
    hostname,
    MAX(kb) AS LastKB 
FROM
    patchstate
GROUP BY hostname 
ORDER BY LastKB DESC;
```

This should provide the results you are looking for.

Comment: yes that's it thanks. I just wonder who gave me -1 and why? Am I to feel guilty that I don't know something and dare to ask? That's not very good approach as it might make people be afraid to post questions not to lose reputation...

Answer (score 1):

Most DBMSs would have thrown an *error* at the sight of this query.
Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL and even MySQL, if it's configured *properly*.

Why?
For *exactly* the reason you've stated.

You've asked the query to return a row for each **hostname**, but also selected the column **kb**.  You *haven't* told the DBMS how to *derive* the value of kb, based on the "key" of hostname, so it's just handing you *any old value* that it happens to come across whenever the "key" changes.

*Every* field you select in an aggregating query has to be *either* in the "group by" clause *or* wrapped in an aggregating function (in this case, **max()** is what you need).